# Semirings (or Rigs)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can anyone give me some famous quotients of semirings or Rigs (i.e. semirings described by generators and relations)? For example M. Fiore and T. Leinster have given the normal form for the elements of the semiring $\mathbb{N}[x]/(x = 1 + x + x^2)=\mathrm{Rig}\langle x|x=1+x+x^2\rangle$ ([arXiv:math/0211454](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211454)). Can you give me another or some papers about quotients of semirings ?

Thank you!